# How to fill auto incremented primary key field from Database instead of explicitly filling it in Kafka Producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I am creating an end to end kafka messaging example.
When I come to the step where I fill User data to kafka topic from a producer, and after setting my schema registry with the following :

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ConnectDefault",
  "namespace": "io.confluent.connect.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "email_address",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "first_name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "last_name",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

and my producer record is :

```
  Producer<String, User> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, User>(properties);

        String topic = "inbox_products";
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("fname");
                user.setEmailAddress("email");
        user.setLastName("lname");
        ProducerRecord<String, User> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String,User>(topic,String.valueOf("key1"),user);
```

No new record is shown in DB.
But I can see from failed_records topic that the row I am trying to send to DB is like :

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "firstName": "topic",
  "lastName": "topic",
  "emailAddress": "topic"
}
```

That means it's sending an empty primary key to db, which should originally be handled in the table users itself.

This is my sink connector config :

```
{
    "name": "postgres-sink-users",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhosr:5432/dbname",
        "connection.user": "dd",
        "connection.password": "dd",
        "topics":"users",
        "insert.mode":"insert",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"kafkaregistry:8085",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"kafkaregistry:8085",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
        "quote.sql.identifiers":"never",
        "errors.tolerance":"all",
        "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"failed_records",
        "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor":"1",
        "errors.log.enable":"true",
        "pk.mode":"record_value",
        "pk.fields": "id"
    }
 }
```

Should I remove "pk.mode":"record_value" from the config as the auto increment is at the db level or remove the id field from my registry schema ?

Comment: `ConnectDefault` should be your Avro class in your producer code... Where does `User` come from? And how did `"topic"` get set as values in your data? Unrelated, but `schemas.enable` is only applicable to JSON, not Strings or Avro

Comment: Maybe no records are in the database because `localhosr` in your connection string is not `localhost`?